# Can I get the Field instance of putfield or putstatic instruction in ASM?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I'm working with [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) and want to manipluate the class file to keep track of some field writes. I've learned `putfield` and `putstatic` instructions are instance of `FieldInsnNode` class in ASM, and I want to inject some code to construct a [Field](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) object at runtime and call other methods taking this `Field` object as an argument.

I did some experiment by compiling a simple Java source code:

```
package com.test.simple;

public class Simple {
    public int a,b;

    public void foo() {
        a = 20;
        b = 10;
    }
}
```

And then use `javap` to examine the class file:

```
$ javap -c -l Simple.class 
Compiled from "Simple.java"
public class com.test.simple.Simple {
  public int a;

  public int b;

  public com.test.simple.Simple();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        
    LineNumberTable:
      line 3: 0

  public void foo();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: bipush        20
       3: putfield      #2                  // Field a:I
       6: aload_0       
       7: bipush        10
       9: putfield      #3                  // Field b:I
      12: return        
    LineNumberTable:
      line 7: 0
      line 8: 6
      line 9: 12
}
```

Here I can find `putfield`s are actually followed by something like `#2`, which I guess are references to the constant pool. (And I have a wilder guess that constant is actually an instance of `Field`)

However, in ASM, `FieldInsnNode` just has 3 fields(namely `owner`, `name`, `desc`) hiding all the details about the constant field so I don't know how to verfy my guesses.

Here my question is:

- If the `Field` objects do lie in the constant pool, how can I retrieve it and push it to the stack in ASM?
- If I can't find the `Field` objects, is that possible to Use `FieldInsnNode.name` and `FieldInsoNode.owner` to instantiate an instance of `Field` (Since there are no public constructors for `Field`)?
- If all of the above won't work, I think I can still just printing out `FieldInsnNode.name` so at least I can know which field does the instruction write to. But it looks like all Strings also lie in the constant pool as well, so how can I build up some instructions to instantiate a String at runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use an `ldc` instruction to load a `String` constant from the constant pool to the operand stack. However you can’t do that with `Field`s. Contrary to your assumption, there is no `Field` instance on the constant pool. The JVM doesn’t use Reflection for its normal operations.

The associated constant pool entry of a `putfield` (etc.) instruction refers to a descriptor which, simply said, contains exactly the information which ASM provided, the owner class, the field name and its type signature.

To get a `Field` instance from these information you can use

```
ldc owner // a Class instance from constant pool
ldc name  // a String instance from constant pool
invokevirtual java/lang/Class getDeclaredField (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Field; // returns the Field
```

The `desc` can be ignored here as Reflection will simply return the uniquely named field regardless of its type.

The ASM library provides the methods for constructing the instruction sequence described above. Be aware that `visitFieldInsn` provides you a `String` for the owner class which [you have to convert to a `Type` instance](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/Type.html#getObjectType(java.lang.String)) before passing to [`visitLdcInsn`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitLdcInsn(java.lang.Object)) as you want to generate an `ldc` instruction producing the associated `Class` instance rather than a `String` instance containing the name of the class.

---

For completeness, starting with Java 7 there is a possibility to get a `MethodHandle` from the constant pool wrapping field operations like `putfield` for a field known at compile-time, but the resulting handle only allows performing the encapsulated field operation using its `invoke` method but not inspecting the properties of the encapsulated field. That is reserved to Java 8 or newer which introduces an [API method for converting such a `MethodHandle` to a `Field`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandleInfo.html#reflectAs-java.lang.Class-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-) but that is not simpler than the three instruction sequence above which works with all JVMs starting with Java 5.

Comment: My links point to ASM’s visitor API but of course, ASM’s tree API follows the same concepts so the information of my answer should be easily adaptable to that API.